# Add an object to a list that matches a specific class

Tags: python, list, class

I have a piece of code that extracts a list of objects from a database. These could match 1 of 3 different classes

I.E:

Event

Asset

PlannerList

I would like to take only the objects that are Events and add them to a list but I don't know how to separate out the objects based on the class they fall under.

I don't have any of my current code to add as it is too long and complex (As it does many different things)

Is it possible to write something along the following line:

If Class == Event?

I realise this isn't much to go on but any advice or a point in the right direction would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: But do You already get the objects as instances of some class  ? or just the raw data packed in dicts ? If that are instances of some class You can always use `isinstance(myObj, Event)`

Comment: That looks like it has solved my issue! Thanks! Could you add it as an answer so I can accept it?